# How can the x86 processor fetch the instruction just after GDT is loaded by a bootloader?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, osdev, gdt

In a typical simple bootloader writing for x86, we have the following code to load the GDT and perform a far jump (note that CS is 0x0  before executing the following code):

```
lgdt gdtdesc
movl %cr0, %eax
orl $1, %eax
movl %eax, %cr0

# Jump to next instruction, but in 32-bit code segment.
# Switches processor into 32-bit mode.
ljmp $0x8, $protcseg

.code32                                             # Assemble for 32-bit mode
protcseg:
```

However, just  after `lgdt` CS is null, pointing to a null descriptor in GDT. So :

1.How on earth can the CPU fetch the correct instruction just after GDT is loaded by `lgdt`?

2.DPL of the code segment to far-jump to is usually 0, does the CPU perform privilege check when doing the far jump?

Answer (score 1):

Until the far jump loads the internal CS base/limit/stuff from a GDT entry, you're not using any GDT entry at all.  It's not *really* even protected mode.

Unlike enabling paging (where instruction fetch for the next instruction treats CS:EIP as virtual in the next instruction after writing CR0), segment stuff doesn't happen until after a writing a segment register causes the CPU to actually read from the GDT.

The CS base address isn't changed by LGDT, and you're still at maximum privilege level with operand-size = address-size = 16, so code-fetch of the `ljmp` instruction just happens.  (Assuming execution of this snippet started in real or unreal mode.)  Being in protected mode affects the meaning of updating CS to `8`, but doesn't affect fetching and running the instruction that does that.

I don't know the formal details of whether it counts as CPL=0 or if it's a special case, or what would happen if your first far jump was to a call gate.  If you want more than that, have a look at https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial and/or Intel or AMD's manuals, or maybe someone else will answer this question.